# solr search slow response to client

Tags: performance, tomcat, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am new to Solr..
I want to ask a question. I have solr with 1 million++ data. I want to compare fulltext search performance between Solr and MySQL by fetch all query result match with the fulltext keywords. I expect that my Solr was faster, but my solr search performance was bad :( sometimes it's more bad than mysql (in query response time).

[solr search query time + response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJft0.png)

[mysql search query time + response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EANY.png)

In the screenshot above, we can see that my solr consume 15.12 seconds to search for keywords in index and mysql just consume 10.31 seconds.

Anyone know the solution ? 
oh ya, i used tomcat with Solr.

Thanks before.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually returning the same set of data? Why would you return 6MB of data? The time is mostly spent transferring, serializing and deserializing content, not actually searching.

Comment: yes @MatsLindh, i have the same data on Solr index and MySQL. I want to test fulltext searching with Solr and MySQL and then compare. I want to retrieve all data match the keywords both in MySQL and Solr index. 

in MySQL retrieval time just 10.31 seconds including query process, transfering data from DB to client, serializing, and deserializing. But why does Solr spent query process, transfering, serializing and deserializing data slower then MySQL ?

I have test Solr search with Solr REST API, but true, my Solr was slow.